# Allow Google Chrome to do cross-site requests

Tags: http, google-chrome

For developing purposes, is there a flag for Google Chrome that will allow for cross-site HTTP requests?

Comment: That would be a horrible thing if there was.

Comment: I guess you have to do it directly on your development site, not sure if possible in Chrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of A way to allow cross site requests, but if you are trying to pull in data from on particular site (ie. the live version of the site you are developing for) you can edit you /etc/hosts file to have test.whateveryourdomainis.com point to localhost, this way you can also have domain specific links in your code that more closely match what they will be on the live site.

By doing this your local files will appear to be hosted remotely, and any cross domain issues will be ignored

Answer (score 4):

Under OSX start Canary/Chrome app with the flag --disable-web-security.

Be careful with this option though.

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome\ Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome\ Canary --disable-web-security
```